# How to get auto generated primary key after inserting or updating record using jdbc template batch update?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I am using spring `JDBC` template for data insertion in Oracle and I have one requirement that I have to bulk insert using spring `JDBC` template batch update and I want auto generated primary key and that key I need to pass in another method but I am not able to get that auto generated primary using batch update.

Can you please provide solution?

Comment: Can you share the code you have so far?

Comment: I'm fairly certain, although not entirely positive, there are two basic ways to do this, neither of which you're going to like. First, you can assign a unique GUID to each object you're inserting and then SELECT the primary keys back out after you've done the insert. Yuck. Similarly, if you can select and know you're getting the data you just inserted, that would do it. The other way is to do SELECT nextval(yourseq), nextval(yourseq), ... for as many records as you're going to insert, then use those values. I do not believe the values you want are otherwise going to be available to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have auto generated PK in oracle,
See sample code:

```
final String insertNewFieldSql = Config.getSqlProperty("insert_new_field_record");      
    GeneratedKeyHolder holder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
    MapSqlParameterSource parameters = null;

    for (ParsedData field : fields) {

            parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
            parameters.addValue("FIELD_1",parsedEmail.getDbRecordId())
                    .addValue("FIELD_2",field.getName());

            namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update( insertNewFieldSql, parameters, holder, new String[] {"PK_FIELD_ID" } );

            Long newFieldKey = holder.getKey().longValue();
            logger.log(Level.FINEST, "row was added: " + newFieldKey);
            }
```

Comment: I think you're doing batch update in the for loop. Is this the good approach?